# Объединить два списка словарей по значению

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Имеется два списка словарей:

```
list1 = [{'company': 'Apple', 'rate': Decimal('1.0')}, {'company': 'Samsung', 'rate': Decimal('1.2')}]
list2 = [{'company': 'Apple', 'tariff__rate': Decimal('3.47')}, {'company': 'Samsung', 'tariff__rate': Decimal('1.10')}]
```

Как объедить всё в один список словарей, добавив для соответствующей компании еще один коэффициент. 
 Должно получиться так:

```
new_list = [{'company': 'Apple', 'tariff__rate': Decimal('3.47'), 'rate': Decimal('1.0')}, {'company': 'Samsung', 'tariff__rate': Decimal('1.10'), 'rate': Decimal('1.2')}]
```

Использую python3.5.3. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл способ, как можно создать такой список в одну строку)

Для того чтобы проходить сразу по двум спискам, воспользуемся методом `zip()`. Он сгруппирует значения списков по парам, и в переменные `i` и `j` будут попадать каждую итерацию словари, находящиеся на одинаковых позициях в списках. Эти словари мы и будем объединять друг с другом.

```
from decimal import Decimal 
list1 = [{'company': 'Apple', 'rate': Decimal('1.0')},
         {'company': 'Samsung', 'rate': Decimal('1.2')}]
list2 = [{'company': 'Apple', 'tariff__rate': Decimal('3.47')},
         {'company': 'Samsung', 'tariff__rate': Decimal('1.10')}]
new_list = [dict(i, **j) for i, j in zip(list1, list2)]
print(new_list)
```

Вывод:

```
[{'rate': Decimal('1.0'), 'tariff__rate': Decimal('3.47'), 'company': 'Apple'},
{'rate': Decimal('1.2'), 'tariff__rate': Decimal('1.10'), 'company': 'Samsung'}]
```

Сделать это можно таким ещё образом:

```
from decimal import Decimal 
list1 = [{'company': 'Apple', 'rate': Decimal('1.0')}, 
         {'company': 'Samsung', 'rate': Decimal('1.2')}]
list2 = [{'company': 'Apple', 'tariff__rate': Decimal('3.47')},
         {'company': 'Samsung', 'tariff__rate': Decimal('1.10')}]
new_list = list()
for i, j in zip(list1, list2):  # Проходим по элементам списков
    i.update(j)  # Записываем всё в один словарь
    new_list.append(i)  # Добавляем словарь в список
print(new_list)
```

Вывод:

```
[{'company': 'Apple', 'tariff__rate': Decimal('3.47'), 'rate': Decimal('1.0')},
{'company': 'Samsung', 'tariff__rate': Decimal('1.10'), 'rate': Decimal('1.2')}]
```

По сути метод `dict(i, **j)` то же, что и `i.update(j)`, только возвращает новый словарь. Об этом пишут [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452995/why-doesnt-a-python-dict-update-return-the-object).

Comment: Способ в одну строку мне понравился, спасибо!)

Comment: Добавьте описание того, как сработает `zip` в данном случае

Answer (score 1):

Если индексы совпадают и размерность массива одинакова, это можно сделать следующим способом:

```
from decimal import Decimal

list1 = [{'company': 'Apple', 'rate': Decimal('1.0')}, {'company': 'Samsung', 'rate': Decimal('1.2')}]
list2 = [{'company': 'Apple', 'tariff__rate': Decimal('3.47')}, {'company': 'Samsung', 'tariff__rate': Decimal('1.10')}]

for x in range(len(list1)):
    list1[x].update(list2[x])
    print(list1[x])
    # {'company': 'Apple', 'rate': Decimal('1.0'), 'tariff__rate': Decimal('3.47')}
    # {'company': 'Samsung', 'rate': Decimal('1.2'), 'tariff__rate': Decimal('1.10')}
```

Сам `list1` теперь выглядит вот так:

```
[{'tariff__rate': Decimal('3.47'), 'rate': Decimal('1.0'), 'company': 'Apple'}, {'tariff__rate': Decimal('1.10'), 'rate': Decimal('1.2'), 'company': 'Samsung'}]
```

Если неизвестно совпадают ли индексы, то мы можем перебирать все значения и проверять совпадают ли названия компаний:

```
for x in range(len(list1)):
    for y in range(len(list2)):
        if list1[x]['company'] == list2[y]['company']:
            list1[x].update(list2[y])
            print(list1[x])
            # {'rate': Decimal('1.0'), 'company': 'Apple', 'tariff__rate': Decimal('3.47')}
            # {'rate': Decimal('1.2'), 'company': 'Samsung', 'tariff__rate': Decimal('1.10')}
```

Список `list1` выглядит таким образом:

```
[{'rate': Decimal('1.0'), 'company': 'Apple', 'tariff__rate': Decimal('3.47')}, {'rate': Decimal('1.2'), 'company': 'Samsung', 'tariff__rate': Decimal('1.10')}]
```

Важно помнить, что **порядок расположения в списках не играет роли и может меняться**.